# What's the standard way of packaging bundles for distribution in symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, bundle

I have some bundles I'm likely to reuse across different projects, or even share with people, and want to package them in a distributable way.

What's the best way to package them for this purpose?

I also was considering distributing it with a sample app, to get people started quickly, is there a more or less standard way to do this?

Comment: Have you read http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html ?

Comment: Check out Composer, it will be the standard dependencies manager as of Symfony2 v2.1. Basically, you define the dependencies for your project in a single json file. Each dependency can have its own dependencies too, defined in its own json file. And then you just install everything with a single command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [*Bundle Structure and Best Practices*](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html) cookbook entry. Also you can learn by watching the existing bundles, which you can find on the [KnpBundles](http://knpbundles.com/) site.

Basically, people create a new project for each bundle on [github](https://github.com/). So, there is nothing special in *packaging* them.

Comment: I guess then people would download my project and copy-paste my bundle into their project. What if my project is more complex, like having additional external libraries on the vendors directory and my bundle depending on them? How can people tell they have to copy more than just the bundle?

Comment: For completeness sake: the documentation only says "A bundle must not embed third-party PHP libraries. It should rely on the standard Symfony2 autoloading instead.", so the repository should contain only the bundle files, the only way to add dependecies is by editing the deps file in your app (you better document well your bundle requirements!). There is no way in Symfony 2.0 to handle dependecies in the bundle automatically. In Symfony 2.1 this is solved by Composer (thanks @ChocoDeveloper).